# mysql index: possible_keys is null but key isn't null

Tags: mysql, indexing

Today, there is a problem using a composite index, such as (`name, age, DESC`), and now go to query `"select * from table ThisTableName where age>15 and desc='test' "`. In this case, the B-Tree index is not in line with the leftmost matching principle, the index possible_keys for null can be understood, but key has shown that the composite index. Why this is the case, possible_keys is representative of the index can be used, if this value is null, key value in principle only for null.

Comment: No table name "select * from where age>15 and desc='test' "

Comment: oh, yes, i miss it.  I want to know why the possible_keys is null, but key isn't null. It's just one example,can't affect  much.

Comment: show your sample data here.

Comment: like this,I ,  create index index_longitude on uni_info(longitude),follow is my execute result:

mysql> explain select longitude from uni_info order by longitude \G; 
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: uni_info
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: index_longitude
      key_len: 9
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1414
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Comment: Your question in unclear to me... Are you asking why the index isn't used?

Comment: I want to know why the possible_keys is null, but key isn't null.

Comment: oh ,thank you warmheated people.I know the reason. beacuse my select option is index , but the options after where is not satify index. so possible_keys is null ,and when it query return field use the index. for example,

       create index index_longitude on uni_info(longitude).
      
      explain select longitude from uni_info where latitude<28  \G

can appear this condition.

Comment: "type: index" and "Using index" say that the query can be performed by looking _only_ at the index.

Comment: `INDEX(desc, age, name)` would be a better order.

Answer (score 4):

I think this snippet from [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain_key) explains it:

> It is possible that key will name an index that is not present in the
>   possible_keys value. This can happen if none of the possible_keys
>   indexes are suitable for looking up rows, but all the columns selected
>   by the query are columns of some other index. That is, the named index
>   covers the selected columns, so although it is not used to determine
>   which rows to retrieve, an index scan is more efficient than a data
>   row scan.

Comment: But it may be not efficient because the whole secondary index would be scanned to find the data needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when possible_keys is null but index has been set - only deleting the index and creating the index with a **new name** helped!

`CHECK TABLE _table_name_ QUICK` and 
`REPAIR TABLE _table_name_ QUICK` did not help